# How to use Bluebird with current TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, bluebird, amd

I just don't get it. Once this was relatively easy, I downloaded the snippet from DefinitelyTyped, it assumed it was globally declared, I added the script and it worked. Now it seems that I have no other option that to use a complex package manager and asynchronous loading system, possibly with an optimizer for production.

Ideally I just want some TypeScript code like this

```
// maybe some import?
Promise.resolve("foo").then(function(msg) { 
    console.log(msg);
}
```

compile to some JavaScript like this:

```
Promise.resolve("foo").then(function(msg) { 
    console.log(msg);
}
```

I want it to be able to run in a browser or in a minimal environment like Rhino. If needed, I can include require.js, almond.js, build with browserify or whatever, but I want it to work without needing XHR.

So far I've tried:

- Using global (ambient) modules: could not find one for Bluebird anymore.
- Using ES6 imports with AMD modules, setting `outFile` to get a bundle of my code and then including files in this order: almond.js, bluebird.js, my-code.js and some code that requires the main module so anything runs: `Error: See almond README: incorrect module build, no module name` (apparently the `bluebird.js` I downloaded from the official page does not define a name in AMD, should I build it myself or what...?)
- The same as in the previous point using full require.js: `missing bluebird`.
- The same as in the previous point with a shim like this: `requirejs.config({shim: { bluebird: { exports: "Promise" }}})`: `exception from uncaught JavaScript throw: Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module` and the entire code of Bluebird in the error message.
- Patching the Bluebird definition file: Not allowed in ES6 mode: `Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.`

I feel like I've wasted too much time for such an apparently simple request, so I'll try asking StackOverflow :)

Comment: Have you considered trying [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) and [ts-loader](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader)? Wherever I need bluebird, I just `import Promise = require("bluebird")`

Comment: In the past I've avoided webpack due to it being reportedly slow, but I could consider it. How hard would be to generate a single (or few) files to run the project without XHRs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the global declaration files from DT, it's now considered best practice to use [typings](https://github.com/typings/typings) instead, importing module declaration files.

Eg. for bluebird, you can just `typings install bluebird`. This code compiles fine for me:

```
import Promise = require('bluebird')
Promise.resolve("foo").then(function (msg) {
  console.log(msg)
})
```

Comment: Do you mean the compiled js? Here is a gist with almost all the code and the commands: https://gist.github.com/pellejacobs/6b5dcf77c4b7713e5635564adcedd718. Does this answer your question?

Comment: My intention is to run it in an embedded JavaScript interpreter, not node. Anything that worked in a basic JavaScript environment (e.g. the browser console without using too much of the DOM) would be fine, but implementing a CommonJS environment myself so require works would be a bit too much. It would be fine if it could be bundled with browserify though.

Comment: Hm. I updated the gist to compile with browserify. Does this do what you intended? https://gist.run/?id=1d36c7ca5c9c942386eebb7f9985ddc5

Comment: Yep :) I was just trying that... So far it seems to work in the browser. Now for the final boss I'm testing it against Rhino.

Comment: Yay! It works with browserify. Given that so far I've only added incomplete implementations `console` and `setTimeout()` this solution seems simple enough. The resulting asset is a single file of 30 KB minified and gzipped, which is a bit more than the original `bluebird.min.js` (22 KB) but still good enough. It isn't too much complex either, especially once I add a few gulp tasks to automate it. I'm marking this as solution.

Comment: No luck: "Compiler reserves Promise in top level scope of a file that uses async functions". TypeScript refuses to redefine Promise.

Comment: If you want it to look more "typescripty", you can do: import * as Promise from 'bluebird';

This works in Typescript 2.

Comment: "it's now considered best practice to use typings instead" - I am under the impression that this is no longer true. Am I correct?

Answer (score 6):

If, like me, you think using `Promise.resolve()` to cast/coerce a Bluebird promise seems like it both defeats the stated purpose of [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/why-bluebird.html) (“Zero overhead abstraction”, “Runs everywhere”, “Spec compatible”, ...) and brings TypeScript to a cumbersome tipping point, consider using `@types/bluebird-global` as follows:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/bluebird-global
```

Import this once in your main entrypoint.

```
// The same Promise API, everywhere.
import * as Promise from 'bluebird'
global.Promise = Promise
```

See [DefinitelyTyped issue #11027](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/11027#issuecomment-297907991) for further context.

Comment: See also https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/10801#issuecomment-275202977

Comment: I tried this but getting now: `Type 'typeof Bluebird' is missing the following properties from type 'Function': apply, call, bind, length, and 4 more.`

Bluebird 3.7.2, bluebird-global 3.5.12

Comment: I got error `Type 'typeof Bluebird' is missing the following properties from type 'PromiseConstructor': all, race, reject, resolve, and 2 more.ts(2740)`