# How to use Bluebird in Typescript 2.1+

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, bluebird, typescript2.1

(I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39231151/how-to-use-bluebird-with-current-typescript) but it is from August and it does not answer my question for the current typescript version.)

I'm currently using Typescript 1.8 in my project and this works fine:

```
import * as Promise from "bluebird";
async function f() : Promise<void> {
  return Promise.delay(200);
}
```

But if I try to compile with Typescript 2.1:

```
index.ts(2,16): error TS1059: Return expression in async function does not have a valid callable 'then' member.
```

Googling the issue of using Bluebird Promises in Typscript, I have also found many github discussions, comments and PRs, but they are all very hard to grasp and while discussing interesting points, I can't find anywhere that says how I'm supposed to get this to work now.

So, how am I supposed to be able to use Bluebird for Promises in Typescript 2.1?

Answer (score 8):

Consider using `@types/bluebird-global` as follows.

```
npm install --save-dev @types/bluebird-global
```

Import this once in your main entrypoint.

```
// The same Promise API, everywhere.
import * as Promise from 'bluebird'
global.Promise = Promise
```

See [DefinitelyTyped issue #11027](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/11027#issuecomment-297907991) for further context.

Answer (score 2):

I asked the same question here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8331

In the end my own answer there worked. Here's how to use it in TypeScript 2.3 without an extra `.d.ts` file:

```
import * as Bluebird from 'bluebird';

export interface DummyConstructor extends Bluebird<any> {
    new<T>(): Bluebird<T>;
}

declare global {
    interface Promise<T> extends Bluebird<T> {
        then(...args: any[]): any;
        catch(...args: any[]): any;
    }

    interface PromiseConstructor extends DummyConstructor {}

    var Promise: Promise<any>;
}

Promise = Bluebird as any;

async function test() {
    console.log('PING');
    await Promise.delay(1000);
    console.log('PONG');
}

test();
```

It's horrible and won't work in the future when targeting native ES7, because in the future `async` / `await` simply won't return Bluebird promises and nothing can be done about that. However, until then and when transpiling to ES5 this will keep working.

In spite of the multiple `any` types, it seems somewhat type-safe. I'm sure it could be improved.